# Cannot read property of getstate of undefined error in react testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs

I am trying to write a very simple test case for the App component but getting "cannot read property getState of undefined" error in `React.DOM.render` line. I am new to testing.

App

```
const store = StoreConfig();

function App(props) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Home />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

App.spec.js

```
it('renders correctly', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    div
  );
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

Comment: What is StoreConfig() ?

Answer (score -1):

The boilerplate CRA test is as follows:

Maybe for your linkElement variable you can search/match for text you know should be rendered by your App component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```